# Оптимизация SQL запроса с GROUP BY и подзапросом

Tags: mysql, sql

Интересует, есть ли способы оптимизировать такой запрос в MySQL.
Цель: возвратить список отсортированных товаров по популярности, при этом оставить только те товары, которые есть в наличии в конкретных складах и которые имеют цену.

| Таблица | Описание | Поля |
| --- | --- | --- |
| products | Таблица с главной информацией о товаре |  |
| products_prices | Таблица с ценами товаров | - product_id - organization_id - price То есть у товара может быть несколько цен |
| product_popularity | Таблица, которая хранит информацию об очках популярности | - product_id (primary key) - total |
| warehouses_products_amount | Таблица, которая хранит информацию о кол-ве товаров на складах | - product_id - warehouse_id - amount Primary key: product_id+warehouse_id |

Запрос:

```
SELECT products.product_id
     , popularity.total as popularity
     , min(prices.price) 
FROM products    
LEFT JOIN product_popularity as popularity ON 
    popularity.product_id = products.product_id 
LEFT JOIN product_prices as prices ON 
    prices.product_id = products.product_id    
WHERE 
    popularity.total >= 1 
    AND products.status IN ('A') 
    AND prices.organization_id IN (10129, 25195) 
    AND
       (select 1 
        from warehouses_products_amount 
        where product_id=products.product_id 
           and warehouse_id IN('32', '33', '34') 
           and amount>0 limit 1
       ) = 1
GROUP BY products.product_id  
ORDER BY popularity.total desc, products.product_id ASC  
LIMIT 0, 6
```

Запрос работает моментально (в 10 раз быстрее), если сделать что-то из этого:

- Убрать GROUP BY products.product_id ИЛИ
- Убрать ORDER BY popularity.total desc ИЛИ
- Убрать подзапрос в условии

К сожалению, explain в mysql не дал мне понять, что происходит иначе когда меняешь запрос.
Я попробовал вместо подзапроса о наличии товара сделать left join - стало еще хуже.
Group by - если убрать, то будут дублирующие товары, т.к. в prices несколько строк соответствуют одному товару. + Мне нужно получить минимальную стоимость этого товара.
Возможно, есть способы избавится от group by, но тогда в других подобных запросах придётся также искать подход для избавления от group by.

Мне интересно, почему этот подзапрос плохо работает вместе с group by / order by popularity . Может быть есть способы как-то сделать иначе ? Или же единственное, что можно сделать это избавится от group by? Если да, то как в такой ситуации лучше от него избавится?

UPD. Explain
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD. SQL структура таблиц.

```
CREATE TABLE `warehouses_products_amount` (
  `warehouse_id` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `product_id` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `warehouses_products_amount`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`,`warehouse_id`),
  ADD KEY `product_id` (`product_id`);

CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `product_id` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `product_code` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `product_type` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'P',
  `status` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'A',
  
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `products`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`),
  ADD KEY `status` (`status`);
ALTER TABLE `products`
    MODIFY `product_id` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

CREATE TABLE `product_popularity` (
  `product_id` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `viewed` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `added` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `deleted` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `bought` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `total` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


ALTER TABLE `product_popularity`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`),
  ADD KEY `total` (`product_id`,`total`);

CREATE TABLE `product_prices` (
`product_id` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`price` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
`percentage_discount` int(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`lower_limit` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`usergroup_id` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`organization_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `product_prices`
ADD UNIQUE KEY `usergroup` (`product_id`,`usergroup_id`,`lower_limit`,`organization_id`) USING BTREE,
ADD KEY `product_id` (`product_id`),
ADD KEY `lower_limit` (`lower_limit`),
ADD KEY `usergroup_id` (`usergroup_id`,`product_id`),
ADD KEY `organization_id` (`organization_id`);
```

Comment: почему у вас left join? а не inner ?

Comment: покажите нормальным текстом create table и имеющиеся индексы. и explain тоже

Comment: Покажите explain данного запроса хотя бы. По запросу: от подзапроса точно надо избавляться. Возможно применять технику последовательной доклейки таблиц после предыдущих операций в вышестоящем запросе. Например сначала отбираете только товары с нужных складов, группируете, после доклеиваете популярность, сортируете, делаете limit. И уже после этого доклеиваете цены только к тому что будем выводить

Comment: Добавил explain, но у mysql он толком ничего не показывает. А что значит доклеивание? Как подобная реализация выглядет и нормально ли будет работать пагинация в этом случае?

Comment: Замените подзапрос, получающий значение, на WHERE EXISTS. Добавьте в таблицу `warehouses_products_amount` композитный индекс `(product_id, warehouse_id, amount)` .

Comment: А зачем популярность вынесена в отдельную таблицу ? Перенести total в таблицу продуктов и у вас на одну склейку меньше.

Comment: И да, последовательная склейка думаю мало что даст, сейчас обратил внимание что в where есть доп условия на каждую из участвующих таблиц (left очень сбивал с толку, казалось что где то записей может и не быть. Кстати, оптимизатор он то же может сбивать с толку. не надо указывать left там где он действительно не необходим)

Comment: А что лучше юзать inner join? Особо на производительность не влияет. Также как и where exists. Популярность в отдельной таблице потому что там 5 параметров популярности и total это их сумма , логично хранить отдельно, конечно можно также хранить в таблице продуктов, но есть такой же запрос который по сумме скидок сортирует и для него тогда проблема не будет решена. Хотелось бы понять, почему group by так губительно действует и есть ли выходы из ситуации.

Comment: Вы когда group by выбрасываете случайно поле price из фразы select не выбрасываете ? 5 полей конечно довольно серьезно, но если задумываетесь о производительности, то сокращение количества join это гораздо важнее. И если хотите понять почему group by так влияет, то надо посмотреть что меняется в explain без него.

Comment: join надо всегда указывать именно такой, какой необходим. Потому что условия в where на таблицу по факту все равно превращают left в inner. А читать запрос сложнее. И да, может в вашем случае оптимизатор и так понимает что это inner, но все равно бывают случаи когда это влияет

Comment: @teran Добавил структуру таблиц. Mike, да в том то и дело что mysql explain показывает одно и тоже. Не понятно что конкретно он делает, либо я не могу научится читать его. По поводу group by: выбрасываю, но он не влияет, тестировал без поля в select всё равно group by затягивает запрос. Хотя виновник основной это конечно подзапрос, ощущение что из-за группировки он очень много раз его дёргает

Comment: Второй вариант - продублировать поле status в таблицу популярности (поддерживать актуальность триггерами). И выбросить из запроса таблицу products. Если конечно в итоге не нужны никакие поля больше из нее

Comment: План вот прямо точь в точь такой же, включая порядок следования таблиц и количества записей ? Ну как вариант, когда данных много, то ему просто долго группировать и от этого не уйти, если конечно не заменить в запросе таблицу prices на подзапрос `(select product_id, min(price) as price from product_prices where organization_id IN (10129, 25195) group by product_id) prices`  Что бы при группировке меньше объем данных был

Comment: Замечания по структуре базы. Много лишних ключей. Например в warehouses_products_amount ключ product_id не нужен, так как это поле является первым в составе другого ключа (первичного), а следовательно всегда может быть использован он при поиске по этому полю. подобные лишние ключи есть и в других таблицах. Ключ по полю status в products вряд ли может быть использован, потому что подозреваю что у него крайне низкая селективность (крайне мало уникальных значений, много записей на одно значение)

Comment: зачем кстати некоторые таблицы innodb а некоторые myisam ?

Comment: myisam для статичных таблиц, где ничего не происходит в основном. Редкие изменения

Comment: @Mike Спасибо, ваш запрос на цены сработал хорошо сделал его в INNER JOIN ( в left работает хуже), в 3-4 раза улучшились показатели. Без group by или без подзапроса конечно улучшается в 10 раз, но и в половину тоже не плохой результат, видимо по другому не сделаешь и стоит просто кэш прилепить (хоть и не люблю я кэшем такие проблемы решать) . Больше спасибо не знал, что в JOIN такие финты можно делать.

Comment: Все таки подумайте об объединении products и product_popularity там полей то не много, записи не длинные будут. у вас этот join явно в половине запросов в системе будет присутствовать, а каждый лишний join даже если на конкретный запрос вроде не сильно влияет, но в сумме на загруженность системы влияет прилично